# Sending notification to notificationbar

Tags: java, android, notifications

Im trying to make a Notification Activity that other classes can reuse and put in extra information. What i am struggling with is how to correctly call the method from another class.

Code for Notification Activity:

public class NotificationTest extends MyActivity{

```
public void showNotification(String s, Context c) {


    // define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    // intent triggered, you can add other intent for other actions

    //Intent intent = new Intent(Sender context, which class to start);

    Intent intent = new Intent(c, Settings.class);

    //PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(sender context, 0, intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, intent, 0);


    // this is it, we'll build the notification!

    // in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0

    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(c)


            .setContentTitle("New Post!")


            .setContentText(s)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)

            .setContentIntent(pIntent)

            .setSound(soundUri)

                    //.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "View",pIntent)

                    //.addAction(0, "Remind", pIntent)

            .build();

    Log.d("Vindsiden", "Notification");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below

    // myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);


}


   }
```

Code for calling the Notification from for example MyActivity :

```
String s= "Notification";
    NotificationTest notificationTest = new NotificationTest();

    notificationTest.showNotification(s,MyActivity.this);
```

The error im getting is :

```
12-05 19:20:34.004  22352-22352/com.vindsiden.windwidget E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vindsiden.windwidget, PID: 22352
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4531)
        at com.vindsiden.windwidget.NotificationTest.showNotification(NotificationTest.java:66)
        at com.vindsiden.windwidget.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
```

Comment: I believe you should put your notification code in separate class (not an Activity) and call it statically from other activities. Otherwise you can place it in your base Activity and each child activity will be able to call your notification.

Comment: Thanks ! ill try it when i get home :) Will update the question when i get to test it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help... I use it. Create a class called OurNotification

Change all Menu.class to where you want it to go on click.

```
public class OurNotification {


public void createNotification(Context context, String title, String msg, String other) {
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(msg);

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Menu.class);

// add so it removes
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

//add vibrate and sound only use if you have the correct permissions in manifest or it will crash
//  long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
//    mBuilder.setVibrate(vibrate);
mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));      
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

if (other != null) {
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    bigStyle.setBigContentTitle(other);
    // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigStyle);
}

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(Menu.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(200, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Then in activity service or where ever call

```
new   OurNotification notificaionToShow = new OurNotification();
```

notificaionToShow.createNotification(getApplicationContext(), "TITLE", "Message", null);

If you want to use the big style change that last null to more text.

Comment: nice work, found after 2hours pure pain with error 'Error: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be certain because I think you changed the class names for the example, but retained the originals in the stack trace.  However, it would appear that this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4531)
```

is being caused by this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Therefore I believe that the Context that you're passing to showNotification method is an Activity that hasn't been created yet.

In the code that calls this method, try swapping out whatever you're passing for Context with `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: To do this test you can simply do c.getApplicationContext() in your  showNotification code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies :-)  what does this actually meen? That I need to call the method after on create?  And what is actually getApplicationContext? Since the context alone isn't enough!

Comment: The application context lives as long as your application is alive and does not depend on the activities life cycle.  Since your exception appears to be caused by passing a Context to your showNotification method that hasn't been created yet, using the application context should help.

Comment: Sadly this didnt seem to help. Changed the code to reflect the canges i tried to make in the code. Also clearified some code so that the StackTrace makes more sense.

Comment: What if you change `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` to `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` does that help?

Comment: Nope, just the same stacktrace. The wierd this is if i copy the code of showNotification into MyActivity it works to call it from MyActivity, but when i try to call the method from another Activity i get just the same error.